# Updating variable from different model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My system has a review process for its Paper object. What I want to do is update the paper status to published if 3 reviews for the Paper are accepted.

I've made the review part and it works. A user basically reviews the paper and once the review is accepted the paper will be given a point.

Is there a way that I can implement using AJAX so that once the review points has come up to 3, it will update the paper status in the database to published?

What I've done which doesn't update the paper's status but shows that it's published:

```
<p class="status">
    <strong>Status:</strong>
    <% status = 0 %>
    <% @paper.reviews.each do |review| %>
        <% status += review.review_status %>
    <% end %>
    <% if status >= 3 %>
        Paper published
    <% else %>
        Paper under reviewing process
    <% end %>
<p>
```

Paper model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :subject

has_many :comments
has_many :reviews

#file dependencies
has_attached_file :pdf,
  :url => "/assets/:attachment/:id/:basename.:extension",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/pdfs/:id/:basename.:extension"

  #validations
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 150 }
  validates :subject_id, presence: true
  validates :version, presence: true
  validates_attachment_content_type :pdf, :content_type => 'application/pdf'
```

Review model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :paper
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use acts_as_state_machine to maintain state of paper

checkout https://github.com/aasm/aasm

```
class Paper < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AASM

  aasm do
    state :under_review, intial: true
    state :published

    event :publish do
      transitions from: :under_review, to: :published
    end
  end

end
```

whenever anyone reviews paper then check if review point is equal or greater than 3 then change paper state to published.

```
paper.publish!
```

Donot forget to add **aasm_state** column in your paper table.

Doing with Ajax is no different, just update paper state in view when review point is greater then or equal to 3.

Comment: How do I perform the check every time someone writes a review? Should it be in the review or paper controller?

Comment: I guess Review belongs to paper, whenever you create a review for paper, check whether paper has sufficient point to move to published state.